# element.style in Firebug

Tags: javascript, css, firebug

am working in a software called (opentripplanner) iam trying to make some changes in the CSS codes, but sometimes the Firebug shows (element.style) for some items CSS, i found some of the items CSS overriden in the JS codes, but for some other items i couldnot find where they are overriden though i looked everywhere..the last option left is to see the Class of the element using the firebug and then try to add it inside the CSS codes with my rules (generating new rules) but i dont really know how to do this ..anyone who can help ?????

Comment: the sofware may have cached version of pages, if it is delete those pages

Comment: I already deleted them...iam asking how to generate new rules in the CSS codes using the class name specified in the Firebug...how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for is [here](http://groups.google.com/group/firebug/browse_thread/thread/ca7700045eba11c9).

Element.style properties are introduced via Javascript and are overriding your CSS settings.